# tkinter should i use tk.Frame or my own tk.Frame.__init__ class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object, tkinter

For my program i currently create a parent/frame by doing

**`tk.Frame(parent, bg = "#E6E6FA"...)`**

but i am curious if i should create my frame using my own class
`class Parent(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args)`

I would then create a frame by doing

```
Parent(parent, {"bg": "#E6E6FA", "width": 1280, "height": 720})
```

This is for my A-Level Computing coursework but i intend to carry on with computing at uni so i would like to know which to use.

Comment: if your class will execute only `tk.Frame.__init__` then don't waste your time and use `tk.Frame(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not adding any special attributes or methods to the frame (ie: your `__init__` is virtually empty), there's no reason to create your own class. You are merely adding complexity without adding any value.